# ValueError: Provided exogenous values are not of the appropriate shape for SARIMAX model

Tags: python, time-series, arima, sarimax

I am trying to run a SARIMAX model on some mortgage prepayment data. I have a list of dataframes clustered by mortgage cohort and separate them into train and test sets based on time. Then I scale the train and test sets and run a step-wise `autoarima` function to come up with the best p, d, and q values for the SARIMAX I'd like to run on each cohort. I have this code here:

```py
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import re
columns = feature_df.columns.tolist()
cols = [c for c in columns if c not in ['ScheduledBalance', 'SMM', 'SRCDate', 'cluster', 'PredictionDate', 'CprTarget', 'bondsec_code', 'Coupon']]
i = 1
mapes = []
new_dfs = []
for df in dfs[0:1]:
    if df.empty is False:
        df.index = df['SRCDate']
        #print(df.index)
        train = df[df['SRCDate'] <= max(df['SRCDate']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]
        test = df[df['SRCDate'] > max(df['SRCDate']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]

        X_train = train[cols]
        y_train = train['CprTarget']
        X_test = test[cols]
        y_test = test['CprTarget']
        
        scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
        X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
        X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
        
        scaler_output = scaler.fit_transform(feature_df[['CprTarget']])
        scaler_output =pd.DataFrame(scaler_output)
        
        train_size=int(len(X_train))
        test_size = int(len(y_test))
        
        print(f"For {df['cluster'].unique()}")
        step_wise = auto_arima(y_train, 
         exogenous= X_train,
         start_p=1, start_q=1, 
         max_p=7, max_q=7, 
         d=1, max_d=7,
         error_action='ignore', 
         suppress_warnings=True, 
         stepwise=True)
        
        
        model = SARIMAX(y_train, 
         exog=X_train,
         order=step_wise.get_params().get('order'),
         enforce_invertibility=False, enforce_stationarity=False)
        
        results = model.fit()
        
        predictions = results.predict(start = train_size, end=train_size+test_size,exog=X_test)
        
        actuals = pd.DataFrame(scaler_output.iloc[train_size:, 0])
                
        predictions=pd.DataFrame(predictions)
        predictions.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        predictions.index=X_test.index
        predictions['Actual'] = actuals['CprTarget']
        predictions.rename(columns={0:'Pred'}, inplace=True)
        
        predictions['Actual'].plot(figsize=(20,8), legend=True, color='blue')
        predictions['Pred'].plot(legend=True, color='red', figsize=(20,8))
```

And this is the [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOvAV.png) I am testing. Here is the traceback for the error I'm getting:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\mlemodel.py:1775, in MLEModel._validate_out_of_sample_exog(self, exog, out_of_sample)
   1774 try:
-> 1775     exog = exog.reshape(required_exog_shape)
   1776 except ValueError:

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 620 into shape (74,20)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [128], in <cell line: 10>()
     45 model = SARIMAX(y_train, 
     46  exog=X_train,
     47  order=step_wise.get_params().get('order'),
     48  enforce_invertibility=False, enforce_stationarity=False)
     50 results = model.fit()
---> 52 predictions = results.predict(start = train_size, end=train_size+test_size,exog=X_test)
     54 actuals = pd.DataFrame(scaler_output.iloc[train_size:, 0])
     56 predictions=pd.DataFrame(predictions)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\wrapper.py:113, in make_wrapper.<locals>.wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    111     obj = data.wrap_output(func(results, *args, **kwargs), how[0], how[1:])
    112 elif how:
--> 113     obj = data.wrap_output(func(results, *args, **kwargs), how)
    114 return obj

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\mlemodel.py:3403, in MLEResults.predict(self, start, end, dynamic, **kwargs)
   3357 """
   3358 In-sample prediction and out-of-sample forecasting
   3359 
   (...)
   3400     including confidence intervals.
   3401 """
   3402 # Perform the prediction
-> 3403 prediction_results = self.get_prediction(start, end, dynamic, **kwargs)
   3404 return prediction_results.predicted_mean

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\mlemodel.py:3302, in MLEResults.get_prediction(self, start, end, dynamic, index, exog, extend_model, extend_kwargs, **kwargs)
   3299     extend_model = (self.model.exog is not None or
   3300                     not self.filter_results.time_invariant)
   3301 if out_of_sample and extend_model:
-> 3302     kwargs = self.model._get_extension_time_varying_matrices(
   3303         self.params, exog, out_of_sample, extend_kwargs,
   3304         transformed=True, includes_fixed=True, **kwargs)
   3306 # Make sure the model class has the current parameters
   3307 self.model.update(self.params, transformed=True, includes_fixed=True)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\sarimax.py:1718, in SARIMAX._get_extension_time_varying_matrices(self, params, exog, out_of_sample, extend_kwargs, transformed, includes_fixed, **kwargs)
   1708 """
   1709 Get time-varying state space system matrices for extended model
   1710 
   (...)
   1714 special handling in the `simple_differencing=True` case.
   1715 """
   1717 # Get the appropriate exog for the extended sample
-> 1718 exog = self._validate_out_of_sample_exog(exog, out_of_sample)
   1720 # Get the tmp endog, exog
   1721 if self.simple_differencing:

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\mlemodel.py:1777, in MLEModel._validate_out_of_sample_exog(self, exog, out_of_sample)
   1775         exog = exog.reshape(required_exog_shape)
   1776     except ValueError:
-> 1777         raise ValueError('Provided exogenous values are not of the'
   1778                          ' appropriate shape. Required %s, got %s.'
   1779                          % (str(required_exog_shape),
   1780                             str(exog.shape)))
   1781 elif self.k_exog > 0 and exog is not None:
   1782     exog = None

ValueError: Provided exogenous values are not of the appropriate shape. Required (74, 20), got (31, 20).
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? Would be useful.

Comment: Sure, added the traceback.

Comment: According to the error message, the number of rows in the exogenous variable does not match the number of time periods you're asking it to predict. Can you provide the value of `test_size` and the value of `X_test.shape`?

Comment: Sure, `test_size` is 31 and `X_test.shape` is (31,20).

Comment: I realized that the `autoarima` objects I'm initializing in `step_wise` returns a SARIMAX model, so there is no need to feed it into another one

Answer (score 0):

A similar question is answered here [SARIMAX out of sample forecast with exogenous data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72072931/sarimax-out-of-sample-forecast-with-exogenous-data/75306649#75306649)

You need at least 74 rows in your testing set for forecasts to learn and the same or more # of rows in the training set. As of now, you only have 31.